# Why is this for loop not correct?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Visual Studio is telling me that this for loop isn't correct.
Error Messages are:

> - type bool unexpected
> - ok is undeclared identifier
> - missing ; before }

---

infos:

> -recordset.Select return a long -MoveNext a bool

```
for (size_t i = 0, bool ok = recordset.Select(Adress::getSQLStatement() + "Where A05.recid = %ld", i); ok; ok = recordset.MoveNext(), i++) {
    at(i).Save(recordset);
}
```

Comment: Because you can't define variables of two different types in one statement.

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as **StenSoft** said. But you can define an anonymous structure in the loops first statement, and initialize that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (struct {size_t i; bool ok;} s = {0, true}; s.ok; ++s.i) {
        s.ok = s.i < 10;
        cout << s.i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But IMHO, [while it works](http://ideone.com/PMwnjI), it's more trouble than it's worth. Better restructure you code.

Comment: I'd suggest a while loop for OP

Comment: @Bernhard, You should record that in an answer :)

Comment: i know its the first attempt of a solution

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can of course rewrite your loop like so:

```
{
    bool ok = recordset.Select(...);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; ok; ok = recordset.MoveNext(), ++i)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

But the meta lesson here is that almost all loops are `for`-loops, and when you think your structure is different, think again. There's probably a rewrite in terms of `for`-loops that makes your logic clearer. Your present code doesn't distinguish an initial error from a "no more records" error later. With the new code, that's now explicitly possible:

```
if (bool ok = recordset.select(...)) 
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; ok; ok = recordset.MoveNext(), ++i) { /* ... */ }
}
else
{
    // handle initial error
}
```

I would probably even get rid of the redundant `ok` variable:

```
if (recordset.select(...)) 
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; ; ++i)
    {
        /* ... */

        if (!recordset.MoveNext()) break;
    }
}
else
{
    // handle initial error
}
```